# I am having issues with coding a game of tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make my first game using Unity and c#. I want my game to be a simple game of tag like I used to play when I was younger. I have tried using "OnCollisionEnter" and I was able to get that to change a counter that gave a bool a label. I realized that while this may work for tagging someone it does not help with other people tagging you. And tips on how I can make my code more like a "Tag Manager"?[My current progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuFCo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the logic such that your script checks to see if you are the tagger using Unity's **tags** property. Then, you could switch the tags of both the players, once you check if the collided object is a player.

Below is the code I suggest you use. I would personally use OnTriggerEnter to have more clearer logic between collider and player. Make sure to have a collider object and a Rigidbody on all players within the scene for the function to be called, and attach your script onto every player within the scene.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {
    // if you are the tagger
    if (gameObject.tag == "Tagger") {
        // and if the collided object is a regular player
        if (col.tag == "Player") {
            // the player is now a tagger
            col.tag = "Tagger";
            // depending on if you want to buildup taggers or switch them around, 
            // the below assignment would vary
            gameObject.tag = "Player";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a Taggable.cs like this, not sure if this is even correct syntax, I don't care to actually write it out and test

```
class Taggable : MonoBehaviour {
      bool it;
      
      private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        var other = collision.collider.GetComponent<Taggable>();
        if(other != null) {
            if(it) {
                other.it = true;
                it = false;
            }else if(other.it) {
                it = true;
                other.it = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public bool it;*

Comment: if you want to keep track of how many times they've been it, you can have 
int numTimes;
and add 1 every time that you tag

Comment: wait, probably drop everything after the else, and the else itself, so that this isn't run twice